# How to make a textarea with some text with HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have this code in my HAML file with rails.

```
= find_and_preserve f.text_area :notes
```

It outputs

```
<textarea id="asdf_notes" name="asdf[notes]"></textarea>
```

How can I make this:

```
<textarea id="asdf_notes" name="asdf[notes]">SOME PLAIN TEXT</textarea>
```

?

It should be easy, but I spent about an hour and found nothing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The textarea should take its contents from the model object linked with the form.

For example, if your form is:

```
= form_for @customer do |f|
```

You'd set `@customer.notes = "SOME PLAIN TEXT"` where appropriate in your controller.